# "This XML file does not appear..." How to see sitemap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sitemap

How can I see what my sitemap looks like when I go to https://anthony-galli.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz? I'm confronted with instead:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>25B779FB11146233</RequestId>
<HostId>
94TdmdgzvdGCMVfKFZYL7Z3JASDFSa18N1YdUoMCtNa3qx6UHajPfMQSeFqfDmgYFHf
</HostId>
</Error>
```

It looks like the sitemap correctly built when I ran:

```
Anthony-Gallis-MacBook-Pro:blog galli01anthony$ heroku run rake sitemap:refresh --trace
WARNING: Toolbelt is currently updating
Running rake sitemap:refresh --trace on ⬢ anthony-galli... up, run.5920
** Invoke sitemap:refresh (first_time)
** Invoke sitemap:create (first_time)
** Invoke sitemap:require_environment (first_time)
** Execute sitemap:require_environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sitemap:create
In '/app/public/sitemaps/':
+ sitemap.xml.gz                                          24 links /  982 Bytes
Sitemap stats: 24 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m00s

Pinging with URL 'http://www.anthonygalli.com/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
** Execute sitemap:refresh

Pinging with URL 'http://www.anthonygalli.com/sitemap.xml.gz':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/sitemap.xml.gz', to: redirect("https://#{ENV['AWS_BUCKET']}.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz"), as: :sitemap
```

**production.rb**

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
      :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

**config/sitemap.rb**

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = 'http://www.anthonygalli.com/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'public/sitemaps/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add posts_path, changefreq: 'daily'
  Post.find_each do |post|
    add post_path(post.slug), lastmod: post.updated_at
  end
end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines
```

**lib/tasks/sitemap.rake**

```
require 'aws'

desc 'Upload the sitemap files to S3'
task upload_to_s3: :environment do
  puts 'Starting sitemap upload to S3...'
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
  bucket = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
  Dir.entries(File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps')).each do |file_name|
    next if %w(. .. .DS_Store).include? file_name
    path = "sitemaps/#{file_name}"
    file = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sitemaps', file_name)
    object = bucket.object(path)
    object.upload_file(file)
    puts "Saved #{file_name} to S3"
  end
end

namespace :sitemap do
  # ...
  desc 'Create the sitemap, then upload it to S3 and ping the search engines'
  task create_upload_and_ping: :environment do
    Rake::Task["sitemap:create"].invoke

    Rake::Task["sitemap:upload_to_s3"].invoke

    SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines('http://www.anthonygalli.com/sitemap.xml.gz')
  end
end
```

[image]

I followed along this tutorial: http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/creating-a-sitemap-with-ruby-on-rails-and-upload-it-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: Possibly a issue with the permissions you have granted within the s3 bucket?

Answer (score 2):

> If you don't have GetPolicy permissions, Amazon S3 returns a 403
>   Access Denied error.
>   *—http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETpolicy.html*

Add this policy (created with https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to your s3 bucket to allow public access to the specific folder `/sitemaps`:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1467935016977",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1467935004623",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::anthony-galli/sitemaps/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In order to diagnose the issue, please update the question with the AWS provided URL of the object.

[image: Screenshot of AWS S3 Console]

Comment: Thanks Man! I added your code to the Bucket Policy Editor at console.aws.amazon.com. I still get the error. Did I put it in the right spot or is your code incorrect? I tried to generate a policy on my own with the link you gave me, but idk what an ARN or Principal is. Thanks again!

Comment: Just checked. The code works for me via Bucket Policy Editor at console: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/step1profit/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.txt . Please  navigate to your `sitemap.xml.gz` file in the console and select it. The properties column should appear on the right. In properties, copy the "Link:" value and past it here.

Comment: Thanks again for the help :) Okay so I took a screenshot of the page [added to question] I think you're talking about to make sure we're on the same page https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-east-1# ;)

Comment: Good start, almost there. From the page in your screenshot: 1) click on the bucket name `anthony-galli` and the bucket view should appear; 2) click on the folder 'sitemaps' and you should see the file `sitemap.xml.gz`; 3) click on `sitemap.xml.gz` and the blue checkbox should become checked; 4) click on `Properties` on the top right navbar and a right column should appear; and 5) locate the `Link`, copy it and update your question with it. I'll update my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: There wasn't a sitemap.xml.gz file so I clicked "Create Folder", but then when I manually created it there was no `Link`. Do you know how I can generate a `sitemap.xml.gz` so the `Link` is there. Thanks for your easy-to-follow steps :) This has been such a complicated process errr

Comment: 1) Navigate to inside the folder you created; 2) click the blue upload button; 3) upload a dummy `example.txt` file; 4) copy the link of `example.txt` using steps above; 5) paste link in browser; and 6) if you're able to access the file with no error message, then I've answered your question `How to SEE sitemap?`. I recommend you accept my answer AND then ask a new question: `How to CREATE sitemap using Karl Varga's Sitemap Generator gem?`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey buddy sorry for the delay. I finally figured out how to get the `sitemap.xml.txt` link. You said post it here:  
https://s3.amazonaws.com/anthony-galli/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz. Not sure where to put it to remove the error posed in question. Thanks for you patience!

Comment: No worries about reposting the question. Since the S3 issue is resolved, I'll have a look at the sitemap gem and respond within a few days.